# Only root can resolve DNS hostnames on Debian

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dns, hostname

I've set up a Debian 7 image on my ODROID U2 a few days ago and apparently I can only resolve DNS hostnames from a root login (`su`, `sudo`). From a normal user, I can ping IP addresses and names defined in `/etc/hosts` just fine. When I ping a domain name, wget a file or clone a git repository it immediately gives the message 'unknown host' or 'Could not resolve host'.

The `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is just the Debian default file and, as the title says, I can ping/install packages/download files just fine from the root account.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first check the permissions on `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  Both of these should have read permissions for all.  Test if you can read these files with `cat` or `less`.  If you can't, then it is unlikely the resolver can.

You can run the resolver on its own with the command `getent hosts google.com`.  Substitute `google.com` with whatever domain you want to look up.

Comment: Permissions for `/etc/resolv.conf` were apparently set wrong. Corrected it with `chmod a+r /etc/resolv.conf` and now it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For Android system, there is another case which would lead to this issue: CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK was enable in kernel. Ref to [this topic](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4611).